# Noob question on how to adapt a code in as2 to flash 5

Tags: flash, actionscript, adobe, actionscript-2

I have this code in as2, it works great, but I need to adapt it to flash5
myName is the variable asociated to a dinamic text on the flash, it shows the hello but never the good bye even if I comment the line myName="hello";
how can I replicate this to work on flash 5?

```
myName="hello";
myVars = new LoadVars();
myVars.load("getScores.php");
myVars.onData = function(raw) {
   myName="good bye";
}
```

Comment: Do you mean Flash player 5 (as in really old version of Flash) or do you want to convert this to AS3?

Comment: I mean Flash player 5, the one that doesn't even accept names for the instance of texts :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LoadVars` is a class of Actionscript 2.0 so it is not supported in Flash 5.
You should use instead the `loadVariables` method of Actionscript 1.0 and using a code such as

```
onClipEvent(load){
    this.loadVariables("file.txt");
}
onClipEvent(data){
    test = "variable: " + variable;
}
```

with this code the `data` event is fired after variables loading. You must put this code on a movieclip instance (not on timeline).

Answer (score 0):

It appears your OnData function never fires, thus the Good Bye text never displays.

try replacing `myVars.onData` with the following:

```
myVars.onLoad = function (success) {
        if (success) {
                // Call your parser here perhaps
        } else {
                // The data didn?t load at all. Display error
        }
}
```

This will either fix the problem or assist you in finding the problem.

Comment: I tryied this:
myVars = new LoadVars();
myVars.load("getScores.php");
nombre1=0;
myVars.onLoad = function (success) {
        if (success) {
                nombre1=1;
        } else {
                nombre1=2;
        }
}
and it only showed the 0

then I tryied this:
myVars = new LoadVars();
myVars.load("getScores.php");
//nombre1=0;
myVars.onLoad = function (success) {
        if (success) {
                nombre1=1;
        } else {
                nombre1=2;
        }
}
and nothing happend =(
thanks for the help anyway =)